# blank reports from real-time streaming data-set in Power BI

Tags: java, rest, powerbi

I have written a java rest api and included the push url to push the streaming data. The problem is, when reports created, they are are blank or empty! Is there something I'm missing? I'm an amateur in Power BI.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("ip", 27017);
    String push_url = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/950bde67-19db-467b- 
        9a41-f80b7cf24ecb/datasets/dde28014-bf2a-46b3-830a-881144a2aec/rows?
key="vQbtAll96T4lJ9OgYBK1MEB6z4IPMOzOyLzkPUM05%2Fzk%2B
1l1S2fezWEKdJA%3D%3D";

    DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("collection");
    DBCursor cursor = table.find();
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        BasicDBObject header = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next().get("header");
        Object number = header.get("number");
        BasicDBObject data = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next().get("data");
        BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList) ((DBObject) data.get("transaction"));
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            BasicDBObject transaction = (BasicDBObject) list.get(i);
            Object transactionID = transaction.get("transactionID");
            document.put("number", number);
            document.put("transaction", transactionID);
            URL url = new URL(push_urls);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(String.valueOf(document));
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your code that you try...

Comment: @JignashaRoyala I've added my code